# How to add value to column conditional on other column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

In pandas, how is it possible to add a value to a column conditional on the string in other column? (something resembling a 2-dimensional slice operation?)

For example, having a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar'],
                   'colx': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'coly': [5, 6, 7, 8]})
```

how is it possible to add 10 to column `colx` if column `name` is foo?

The resulting df would look like this:

```
   colx  coly name
0    11     5  foo
1    12     6  foo
2     3     7  bar
3     4     8  bar
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `loc` operator to perform slicing when you want to modify the values:

```
df.loc[df.name == 'foo','colx'] += 10
```

The uses the underlying slicing methods of pandas which will be way faster than looping or using an apply on your dataframe. Allthemore if your dataframe gets big.

EDIT:

If you need multiple conditions, you will need brackets, for instance :

```
df.loc[(df.name == 'foo') & (df.coly == '5'),'colx'] += 10
```

Comment: How can I give two conditions here? If say, name is 'foo' and coly is '5', then add 10 to colx